# How could serial upvoting result in 81 rep?

Tags: support, serial-voting

Today I 'lost' 81 rep due to serial upvoting reversal. How is this value possible?

- +10 for upvote on an answer.
- +5 for upvote on a question.

What am I missing that could contribute a +1 or +6?

Comment: Hm. If I had to guess, maybe the script reverses all votes from the perpetrator to you in a certain timeframe, as opposed to only upvotes. Could be someone went through all your questions, upvoted 17 of them and downvoted 2.

Comment: Sort of balances the +1 upvote you got yesterday somehow...

Comment: @lun 17 ? Isn't that too much?

Comment: @Martin 5*17 = 85

Comment: @Phr none of your questions were upvoted

Comment: @lunboks If so, then I'd argue that the heuristic is broken. If someone goes through and reviews a user's history and upvotes/downvotes accordingly, I'd call that a "proper review" not "serial upvoting". Can the user help it if they mostly ask good questions? :p

Comment: @Martin Ah, that's what you mean. Well, there is that. :)

Comment: Actually I'm not getting it somehow: You earned only 191 points from upvotes + 15 from accept. How is this possible? I'm probably going to open bug report

Comment: @lunboks Also serial down-votes are reversed, not just up-votes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You hit rep cap and the last vote you got only gave you ONE reputation point. That's it

Comment: The only question is: Why did you capped even before 200 reputation? You have only 191 points from yesterday

Comment: IIRC I definitely capped fully yesterday, and then some. (Although some of it was apparently upvoting.) I hope that in this situation any non-serial-upvotes that were previously denied rep get their rep restored; my faith in the technical prowess an anal-retentiveness of the s/o team to have gotten that right.

Comment: @Phrogz: Yes, when the votes get reversed, it recalculates the rest of your votes for the day. You won't lose out on those other votes because of their actions.

Answer (score 7):

One possible explanation would be that you've hit the rep cap, and some of the upvotes didn't gain you any rep, although they were still counted as votes.

Seeing how you were very close to the rep cap yesterday, that's probably it.